# tab-delimited file in xamarin

Tags: parsing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, csv

I have a tab-delimited text file, but I have absolutely no idea what to do to: include the file in the project so I can use it, read the text, and parse the text. I'm using a Xamarin PCL so I cannot use File class. I don't even know where to start, so if anyone could help me out with this, that would be amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: is this a file that you are downloading at runtime, or is it a static file you need to include at build-time?  What are you doing with the data in the file?

Comment: @Jason It is currently a static file. I will simply be reading data from this file at first and loading it into memory, but eventually I will try and alter it

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/